# Error 403 forbidden with PySocks and imaplib/smtplib

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, http-status-code-403, imaplib, pysocks

I have a question

Has anyone ever tried using imap/smtp with proxies

I'm trying pysocks with imaplib/smtplib but datacenter proxies (HTTP proxies from Proxiware) aren't working with it, I get an error 403 stating that connect tunneling isn't supported by the proxies

[image: HTTP 403 Forbidden error]

The only thing I could find about it was a github issue still open from Sep 2020
https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks/issues/146

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Please don't out error messages in screen shots, they're not searchable.

Comment: 403 can mean a lot of things, any of the reasons an HTTP server may return 403: bad or missing authentication, configured to block arbitrary CONNECT verbs, etc. Since CONNECT is usually used for HTTPS tunneling, it may only allow port 443, etc.  You'll have to check your documentation/admin/IT help to find out why.